# Find $\lim\frac{f(x)}{x}$ provided that $\lim(f(x+1)-f(x))=l$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Suppose $f$ is continuous on $(a,\infty)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}[f(x+1)-f(x)]=l$. Find $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$.

*Proof*  Suppose $l<\infty$. Let $p>l$. There exists $\xi>a$ such that
$$\tag{1}f(x+1)-f(x)<p$$
whenever $x\geq\xi$.

Fix $x>\xi$. Choose an integer $n$ so that
$$\tag{2}\xi\leq x-n<\xi+1\mbox{.}$$
By (1),
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=\left(\sum^n_{i=1}f(x-i+1)-f(x-i)\right)+f(x-n)\\
&\leq np+f(x-n)\mbox{,}
\end{aligned}$$
so that
$$\tag{3}\frac{f(x)}{x}\leq\frac{np+f(x-n)}{x}\mbox{.}$$
By (2),
$$\tag{4}1-\frac{\xi+1}{x}<\frac{n}{x}\leq1-\frac{\xi}{x}\mbox{.}$$
Observe that (3) and (4) holds for any $x>\xi$ and $n$ satisfying (2). By continuity of $f$, $f$ is bounded on $[\xi,\xi+1]$. Hence if we let $x\rightarrow\infty$ in (3), we obtain
$$\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\leq p\mbox{.}$$
Since $p$ is arbitrary,
$$\tag{5}\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\leq l\mbox{.}$$
Notice that (5) holds for $l=\infty$. In a similar fashion, we have
$$\tag{6}\liminf_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\geq l\mbox{.}$$

(5) and (6) implies that $\lim\frac{f(x)}{x}=l$.$\tag*{$\square$}$

Is this correct? I am not sure about the "Observe ..." part.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem

Comment: It should be pointed out to both the asker and other potential answerers that Stolz-Cesaro is not quite a silver bullet here. The theorem guarantees convergence of sequences, and a not entirely obvious continuity argument is necessary to get to the final continuous result. There is probably a more elementary proof.

Comment: It turns out your conjectured consequence is false: consider $\phi(u) = \sqrt u$ and $x=0$ for example.